# how to set list view last view on Top on item click?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-view

I have two views and both view have listview and second listview overlap the first view in half screen. onitem click my audio play and selected item highlight. when audio change it give highlight to next row and play audio. 
Now i want when ever the audio end the next view set on top  of screen. but last view is not working not set on top i am using this line of CODE

```
lsvwarbic.setScrollY(vyt.getHeight()+5*getHeights()/100);
```

Comment: have you tried setSelection() method.

Comment: yes, it selected... but it does not scroll to last item on top view.

Answer (score 0):

Try setSelection() in your code.
But after calling setSelection(), call yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

NotifyDataSetChanged() will recreate your listview and update the ui.

Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: wherever, you change the data of listview or want to update listview UI, You must have to call notifyDataSetChanged() method,

Comment: dont want change or add date. data is populate once in a listview. i just want when ever item click it move to top view of listview...